# How to make Node.js app under IIS on azure VM public?

Tags: node.js, azure, iis

I installed my Node.js app on Azure VM, and currently it's working under IIS.
Everything looks good but now I need to make it public, accessible by www.mysite.com

I've registered mysite.com domain but I don't know how to connect the VM, Node.js app and this domain name together?

(I remember I found some very useful article for asp.net mvc app, doing the same but unfortunately I can't find it anymore and I'm stuck).

Thanks

UPD:
1) Set up somehow that your app works on localhost:80

2) Firewall set up? (Not sure)

3) Set up the domain pointing to your VM at your provider (usually through CNAME)

Profit! (If you are masochist :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685554/how-do-you-get-an-existing-domain-you-own-to-point-to-azures-servers

Comment: Thanks but the very first step is unclear. How to make app running as soon as I enter myvm.cloudapp.net in the browser?

Comment: Okay, I tried something but it's not working. I don't know how to specify that when I enter localhost:80 it should show my app? Please HELP!!!

Answer (score 1):

Go to your domain hoster's admin panel (be that GoDaddy, Namecheap, etc) and add an `A record` pointing to your VM:

```bash
$ dig example.com

www.example.com.   3600     IN   CNAME   example.com.
example.com.       3600     IN   A       PUBLIC.IP.ADDR.OF.YOUR.VM
```

Make sure you are using a [reserved public IP address](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2017/01/18/step-by-step-assigning-a-reserved-ip-address-to-an-azure-vm/), thus making sure the IP address stays if you **Stop Deallocate** your VM.

If you'd rather not spin up and manage a VM with IIS (which is like buying a hotel chain just to take a shower), you may want to look into [hosting your Node app on App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs).

The walkthrough uses [azure-cli](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) but you can do all that from the Portal UI as well if you're not comfortable with the CLI stuff.

You need to be aware of this gotcha in Azure App Service with Node: don't hardcode a port number to listen on, use `process.env.PORT` instead (which becomes a named pipe at runtime). [See this answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36425811/4148708).

You can use your [own domain with App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

Comment: I really appreciate your humur but it's kind of a little bit inappropriate here. Because I googled the whole day without any result. And what you suggest just doesn't work (I tried) because of one small thing - I could not do the first step what was to run the app on localhost:80. Finally I figured out what was the reason - I removed the default app and after that everything got broken. I started restoring IIS but it took several hours and I didn't have patience to wait. As a result I gave up the idea to run node.js app under IIS on azure because it's most STUPID thing ever done. Thanks!

Comment: You are way overengineering this. Why not use App Service (PaaS)? No VMs, no IIS to setup and manage, just deploy the code. See my edited answer.

Comment: I totally agree... I know how to get my own domain and app. The problem is how are you going to host it? I actually started from this one, just created an app service, FTPied files there and... it didn't work. I don't know why. I had 500 error and logs I could see said nothing. I found "details" but they didn't actually have any.  I moved to VM just to see what's going on and failed again...Then, guess what? I googled, found that Heroku can host nodejs app (simple app for free!) and it took 2(just 2!!!) hours to put and run my app there. Everything worked!

Comment: BTW process.env.PORT is always empty, how can I rely on it?